# mysql: insert record if not exists else return the id of record

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

i need to insert unique values in a table, and need the ids of records, need to insert those id's in relationship table, 
need the query to insert the record if not exists return the inset id, if exists return the record primary key(id).

and i want to do this for multiple values, like orange, mango, banana, like batch insert.

schema:

```
------------
id | tag   |
------------
1  | orange|
------------
```

i have trid this for a single record

```
INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag`) 
SELECT 'myvalue1' 
FROM tags
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `tags` WHERE `tag`='myvalue1') 
LIMIT 1
```

posted the question to figure out some optimized solution, i don't want to use extra loops in the code to match the values from db.

Comment: Please learn to use the code format button in the question editor

Comment: thanks, i will be taking care of formating

Comment: mysql does have an update or insert into 'tag' statement

Comment: Probably ought to just write a stored procedure which does a select first in this case.  Note: getting an already existing ID is easy.  Getting the ID of a new record created after using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` is a bit of a nightmare.

Answer (score 15):

There is an example on the documentation page for [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

Your query would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag`) VALUES ('myvalue1')
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=LAST_INSERT_ID(id), `tag`='myvalue1';
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: the problem with this method is that when it does actually perform an insert (at least with MySQL8.0 / InnoDB) is that it can cause fairly radical shifts in id's. For example, as a test case - I made a small table with 4 rows of id's and email's. I used this example with the second (id=2) email I inserted, and it worked as you described. However, when I inserted a new email address, I ended up with 5 rows with id's 1, 2, 3, 4, and 7.

Comment: @CreationTribe, I don't know what you mean by "inserted a new email address". Maybe you can provide more info in a separate question. One caveat to keep in mind is that `ON DUPLICATE KEY...` requires a unique key on the column being inserted to trigger the duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the mysql state to insert if not exists and return the id either it new insertion or old

```
    INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag`) 
SELECT 'myvalue1' 
FROM tags
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM `tags` WHERE `tag`='myvalue1') 
LIMIT 1;
select * from brand where `tag`='myvalue1'
```

Comment: This one actually works much better than the one proposed by Marcus Adams (no offense man). This one doesn't stagger the auto-increment values and skip stuff.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 methods listed in the below link, please have a look and use whichever suits you.

- Method 1: `SELECT`, then `INSERT`
- Method 2: `try { INSERT } catch { SELECT }`
- Method 3: `INSERT IGNORE` then `SELECT`
- Method 4: `INSERT INTO... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

http://mikefenwick.com/blog/insert-into-database-or-return-id-of-duplicate-row-in-mysql/

Comment: Link Dead.  404 404 404

Comment: Looks like web archive has a snapshot of the article. https://web.archive.org/web/20140110034752/http://mikefenwick.com/blog/insert-into-database-or-return-id-of-duplicate-row-in-mysql/