# Long IDs vs Short IDs

Tags: node.js, uuid, uniqueidentifier

Currently in my Node.Js app I use `node-uuid` module for giving unique IDs to my database objects.

Using `uuid.v1()` function from that module I get something like

```
 81a0b3d0-e4d0-11e3-ac56-73f5c88681be
```

Now, my requests are quite long, sometimes hundreds of nodes and edges in one query. So you can imagine they become huge, because every node and edge has to have a unique ID.

Do you know if I could use a shorter ID system in order to not run into any problems after the number of my items grow? I mean I know I could get away with just the first 8 symbols (as there are 36^8 > 2 Trl combinations, but how well will it perform when they are randomly generated? As the number of my nodes increase, what is the chance that the randomly generated ID will not fall into the already existing ones?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you're really concerned about uuid collisions you can always simply do a lookup to make sure you don't already have a row with that uuid. The point is that there is always a very low but non-zero chance of a collision given current uuid generators, especially with shorter strings.

Here's a post that discusses it in more detail
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/130261/uuid-collisions

One alternative would be to use a sequential ID system (autoincrement) instead of uuids.

Comment: Most databases don't insert an rows with existing ids. He might not need a extra look up for that.

Comment: @Jephron - any recommendation about a node.js module i could use?

Comment: You just want to make sure you're not inserting a row with a UUID which already exists, right? I don't know of a module that automates that, but it's pretty simple to check yourself. You could even create your own module that does it. Just query your database with the UUID you've generated to make sure no rows with that UUID already exist. If it does, generate a new UUID and try again. Just out of curiosity, is there any reason you can't just use an auto-incremented key?

Comment: As a somewhat cleaner alternative, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479971/mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-else-return-the-id-of-recode